# find and copy directories

Tags: directory, find, copy

I have this directory structure:

```
.../current folder/Bx/Px/
```

where `x` are different numbers, like `x`=`1`, `2`, `3`... and so on.

I want to find directories `P*` in the current folder and then copy all of them into the folder `asd`, which is also in the current folder. For files I usually do:

```
find . -name P* | cpio -pdm asd
```

but I have no idea, how to do this with directories. I tried something like:

```
find . -name P* | cpio -D -pdm asd
```

in different configurations, but it does not work.

Comment: `-type d` will find directories only.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: If you only want to copy the directories (and their contents) and not use an archive, then `cp` will do instead of `cpio`. Something like `find . -name "P*" -type d -exec cp {} /path/to/asd \;`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but not exactly, to what [@Jos said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426525/find-and-copy-directories#comment2484108_1426525) you can use this `find` command:

```bash
find . -type d -name "P*" -exec cp -r {} ./asd \;
```

- `-type d`: find directories only.
- `-name "P*"`: search for all items with their name starting with `P` in a case-sensitive way.
- `-exec`: execute the specified command.
- `cp -r {} ./asd`: copy (`cp`) the found directories matching the criteria `{}` with their contents `-r` to the `asd` directory in the current directory `./`.
- `\;`: apply the `cp` operation for each item found (`\` is used to escape `;`).

Remember that `find` by defaults looks recursively for items matching the specified criteria, so it will find directories matching the specified criteria in subdirectories too. If you are interested in matching directories in the current directory only, add the `-maxdepth 1` option before `-type d`. Also see [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html).

**Note:** Make sure to first test the above command before applying it to your actual data to make sure that it works as intended. Also, it is always a good idea to keep backups of your data.